# Solvable groups that are linear over $\mathbb{C}$ but not over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, solvable-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated finitely presented virtually solvable group. Assume that there exists an injective representation $\Gamma \to \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is it true that there always exists an injective representation $\Gamma \to \operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb{Q})$ for some $m$?

A natural way of arguing that comes to my head is the following. Let $R_n(\Gamma)$ be the *representation scheme* of $\Gamma$ in $\operatorname{GL}_n$ (that is, the subscheme in $\operatorname{GL}_n^{\times s}$, where $s$ is the number of generators, which is defined by the relations viewed as algebraic equations on matrix elements).  Inside it, we have the subset of injective representations $R^\text{inj}_n(\Gamma) \subseteq R_n(\Gamma)$. If it were an algebraic subvariety, one could say that since $R^\text{inj}_n(\Gamma)$ contains a point over $\mathbb{C}$, it contains a point over a number field $K$. Thus $\Gamma$ has an injective representation with values in $\operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ which by restriction of scalars gives rise to an injective representation with values in $\operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb{Q})$ with $m=n[K:\mathbb{Q}]$.

The problem here is that $R^\text{inj}_n(\Gamma)$ is not a Zariski open subset. One has to take out the subvarieties that correspond to all possible kernels of representations of rank $n$ and this is a countable union of subvarieties. Even in the simplest case when $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}$ and $n=1$ one should take out all the roots of unity (that is, $R^\text{inj}_n(\Gamma)=\mathbb{G}_m\setminus \mu_{\infty}$).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a complement to YCor's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458522), adding some references.

> **Notation.** For $G$ a group and $x$, $y$ two elements of $G$, we  set $x^y := y^{-1}x y$ and $[x, y] := x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$.

> **Definition.** A group is said to have *finite Prüfer rank $r$* if every finitely generated subgroup can be generated by $r$ elements and $r$ is the least such integer.

The answer to the question stated in the body of the post is **no**, as witnessed by the following **finitely presented** counter-example due to Baumslag and Remeslennikov [1, Theorem 11.1.5]:

> **Claim.** Let $$G = \langle a, s, t \, \vert \, a^t = a a^s, [a, a^s] = 1 = [s,t] \rangle$$ be the Baumslag–Remeslennikov group. Then $G$ is a finitely presented torsion-free metabelian group with subgroup $\langle a, s \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z} \wr \mathbb{Z}$.

> *Sketch of the claim's proof.* Check that $[G, G] = \langle a^{s^i} \,\vert\, i \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{Z})}$. It follows immediately that $G$ is torsion-free and metabelian. See [1, Proof of Theorem 11.1.5] for details.

**Note.** More generally, a theorem of Baumslag and Remeslennikov (1973) states that every finitely generated metabelian group can be embedded into a finitely presented metabelian group. Even more to the point is Thomson's theorem (1977) [2]: every finitely generated linear soluble group can be embedded into a finitely presented linear soluble group. Starting from $H = \mathbb{Z} \wr \mathbb{Z}$, Thomson's theorem yields a linear and finitely presented soluble group $G$ containing $H$. This group is made explicit in the above claim.

> **Corollary.** The Baumslag–Remeslennikov group, i.e., the group $G$ of the above claim, is $\mathbb{C}$-linear but not $\mathbb{Q}$-linear.

The proof of the previous corollary relies on the following two lemmas.

> **Lemma 1. (YCor's key argument)** A finitely generated soluble $\mathbb{Q}$-linear group has finite Prüfer rank.

> **Lemma 2.** (Levic–Remeslennikov, 1969 [3] and [4])
> A finitely generated torsion-free metabelian group is $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

> *Proof of Lemma 1.* Because of Mal'cev's Theorem (1951), see e.g. [1, Theorem 3.1.6.ii], it suffices to show that any finitely generated subgroup of $T_n(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ ($n \ge 1$), the group of invertible upper $n \times n$  triangular matrices over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, has finite Prüfer rank. Such a subgroup $H$ is a finitely generated subgroup of $T_n(K)$ for some number field $K = K(H)$. It is therefore the extension of a subgroup $N$ of $U_n(K)$, the $n \times n$ unipotent matrices over $K$ by a finitely generated subgroup $Q$ of $(K^{\times})^n = (K \setminus \{0\})^n$. Since $Q$ is a finitely generated Abelian group, it has finite Prüfer rank and so has $N$ since the additive group of $K$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-linear space. Now, it is an easy exercise to show that the property of having finite Prüfer rank is stable under taking extensions.

> *Proof of the corollary.* The Baumslag–Remeslennikov group is $\mathbb{C}$-linear by the Claim and Lemma 2. It cannot be $\mathbb{Q}$-linear because of Lemma 1. Indeed, it contains a subgroup of infinite Prüfer rank, namely $\langle a, s \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z} \wr \mathbb{Z} \supset \mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{Z})}$.

**Note.** As pointed out by YCor in a comment, a simple and direct way to show that the Baumslag-Remeslennikov group $G$ is linear is to leverage the semi-direct decomposition $$G \simeq \mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{Z})} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}^2 \subset \mathbb{Z}[s^{\pm 1}] \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}[s^{\pm 1}, t^{\pm 1}])^{\times}.$$ The Magnus Embedding Theorem (1939), see e.g. [1, 11.3.2] may serve a similar purpose in more general situations.

---

- [1] J. Lennox and D. Robinson, "[The Theory of Infinite Soluble Groups](https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198507284.001.0001)", 2004.
- [2] M. Thomson, "Subgroups of Finitely Presented Solvable Linear Groups", 1977.
- [3] E. Levic, "Representation of soluble groups by matrices over a certain field of characteristic zero", 1969.
- [4] V. Remeslennikov, "Representation of finitely generated metabelian groups by matrices", 1969.

Comment: For Lemma 2: in the particular case of a group of the form $G\ltimes R$ with $R$ a domain and $G\subset R^*$, one has the obvious linear representation of the form $\begin{pmatrix} g& r \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $g\in G$, $r\in R$. This is even more elementary than Magnus' embedding.

Comment: @LSpice Very right, thanks ! Fixed.

Answer (score 28):

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$No, it's not true that every finitely generated solvable group that is linear over $\mathbf C$ is also linear over $\mathbf Q$. For instance, f.g. solvable subgroups of $\GL_n(\mathbf{Q})$ have finite Prüfer rank, but not all f.g. solvable subgroups of $\GL_n(\mathbf{C})$.

For instance, the wreath product $\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$ is not $\mathbf{Q}$-linear, although it is linear in dimension $2$: fixing any transcendental element $t$, it can be identified to the subgroup
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}t^n &P(t)\\0&1\end{pmatrix}:n\in\mathbf{Z},\;P\in\mathbf{Z}[t,t^{-1}]\right\}.$$

---

To make the whole self-contained: if $G$ is a solvable group and $[G,G]$ contains copies of $\mathbf{Z}^d$ for unbounded $d$ then $G$ is not linear over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Proof: by contraposition: suppose that $G$ is linear over $\mathbf{Q}$, say $G\subset\GL_n(\mathbf{Q})$. Passing to a finite index subgroup, $G$ has a connected Zariski closure. Hence there is a finite extension $L$ of $\mathbf{Q}$ such that $G$ is conjugate into the upper triangular subgroup of $\GL_n(L)$. So $[G,G]$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the upper unipotent (= upper triangular with identity diagonal) subgroup of $\GL_n(L)$. The latter is an iterated extension of $n(n-1)/2$ copies of $L$. Hence its free abelian subgroups have bounded rank, say $\le \dim_{\mathbf{Q}}(L)n(n-1)/2$.

(For the above matrix group $\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$, the derived subgroup is the ideal $\{P\in\mathbf{Z}[t,t^{-1}]:P(1)=0\}$.)

Comment: More generally, given a field $K$ and $n\ge 1$, the wreath product $\mathbf{Z}^n\wr \mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{Z}[t_1^{\pm 1},\dots,t_n^{\pm 1}]\rtimes \langle t_1,\dots,t_n\rangle$ is linear over $K$ if and only $K$ has characteristic zero and transcendence degree $\ge n$ over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: What if one would ask instead, whether each $\mathbb{C}$-linear group is residually $\mathbb{Q}$-linear?

Comment: @HenrikRüping a f.g. $\mathbf{C}$-linear group is residually finite, hence residually $\mathbf{Q}$-linear (f.g. can't be dropped for free since $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\bar{\mathbf{Q}})$ is not residually $\mathbf{Q}$-linear). Your question might become more interesting if you ask "residually linear in bounded dimension".